# How to redirect inside PWA application

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Domains of our project are always get in black list.

How can we send information to PWA about new mirror-domain and get it redirected to it?

When the domain is getting blocked, service-worker doesn't wake up at all and we see page with error. How can we wake it up and make request to our redirector for new working domain?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide info what have you tried so far, why wasn't it working, and info on how is you PWA structured (are you using a framework? which one?)

Comment: Hi! We used webpack for building PWA. Main problem that we can't start service-worker if domain is blocked. It seems like service-worker needs to receive data from site before starting.

Comment: Can you edit the question to provide fuller information?